# R deldir installation error: lzma decoder corrupt data

Tags: r, deldir

I have been attempting to install the R (4.1.0) package 'deldir' on a macos platform, i.e.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deldir/index.html

following

```
install.packages('deldir')
```

I get the following warning(s) - like the one below, but iterated dozens of times:

```
18 | 23001 continue
      |     1
Warning: Label 23001 at (1) defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
gfortran -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2      
-c mnnd.f -o mnnd.o
mnnd.f:16:5:
```

Followed by the error message:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to  see invocation)
make: *** [deldir.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘deldir’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.1/Resources/library/deldir’

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/5s/x2m_2x714s90wchtvd2ylhf80000gn/T/RtmpWxpS5.                    /downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In readRDS(dest) : lzma decoder corrupt data
2: In install.packages("deldir") :
installation of package ‘deldir’ had non-zero exit status
```

I was able to install several other packages without any issue today, so this is only coming up with the 'deldir' package. What does the

```
lzma decoder corrupt data
```

error mean in the context of the readRDS(dest) function, as I think this error is what is driving everything else, and what, if anything, can be done about it?

Comment: The warnings about labels don't matter, you can ignore them.  You should show us the first "error", which probably comes just before the "compilation failed" message.

Comment: The "lzma" message is likely from an attempted download of the list of available packages on whatever CRAN mirror you were using.  Try a different one; `cloud.r-project.org` (hosted by Posit) is quite reliable and up to date.

Comment: Final suggestion:  update to current R, and then you'll be able to download binaries, and won't have to worry about compiling the package.

Comment: I just appended the missing part of the error message (immediately above "compilation error")

Comment: I think that sort of error comes if you use an incompatible Fortran compiler.  The main one available from `mac.r-project.org/tools` is for R 4.3.0; I don't know which one you would use for R 4.1.0.

Comment: If I update to R 4.3, I'll also have to go back and reinstall all of the packages that I need and use. While I can and should do this eventually, what would you suggest as the quickest short-term fix? Would it be a matter of finding the version of Fortran compatible with 4.1.0? As I mentioned, this is the first and only compiled package where I experienced this issue, so presumably the Fortran compiler I have doesn't have compatibility issues with anything else.

Comment: The quickest short term fix is to update to R 4.3.0 and use binaries of packages from CRAN.